# Lmfit Regression with multiple inputs but only one predictor variable

Tags: python, statistics, regression, scipy-optimize, lmfit

Im trying to fit a function described as below:

Y = 10*(b+5/c0+c1*x) assuming x is the predictor variable and Y is the predicted variable.

However, b is also an array with the same length as x and y, and it varies for each x value.
I define the function as follows:

```
def func(x,b,c0,c1):
    return 10*(b+5/c0+c1*x)
```

where x is the predictor variable
b is an array with the same length as X (each x value has a corresponding b value)
c0 and C1 are model coefficients

Im trying to perform regression between y and x using lmfit Module, however, it seems that I cannot define parameters as arrays.

The code below gives the following error:

```
model = Model(func)
params = model.make_params(b=data["b"].values,c0=0.429, c1=0.867)
result = model.fit(Y, params, X=x,calc_covar=True)



"ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"
```

I'm only interested in the relation between y and x, so is this way of doing it statistically wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Please, joint to the question at least one representative example of data (numerical, not graphical).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the language of lmfit, your `b` is "independent data", just like `x` in that it is a predictor, not a variable to be optimized in the fit.

By default, the first argument to a model function is assumed to be the one and only independent variable. Function arguments that are not keyword arguments with a non-numerical default value will be turned into variable parameters for the fit.

But you can specify different or other independent data as with

```
model = Model(func, independent_vars=['x', 'b'])
params = model.make_params(c0=0.429, c1=0.867)
result = model.fit(Y, params, X=x, b=data['b'], calc_covar=True)
```

FWIW, the fact that `b` is an array of the same length as `x` is actually not important to `lmfit.Model`: independent variables can be of any type.  So, you could write your model function as

```
def func(predictor, c0, c1):
    return 10*(predictor['b']+5/c0+c1*predictor['x'])
```

and then use that as

```
model = Model(func)
params = model.make_params(c0=0.429, c1=0.867)
result = model.fit(Y, params, predictor={'x':x, b: data['b']}, calc_covar=True)
```

That may seem like overkill here, but it can be helpful for more complex problems.

Comment: It works perfectly. I agree using a dictionary makes more organized especially when there are many variables. Thanks for the explanation.